# MYSQL CONNECTOR On load data local file: file could not be read

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to  load a normal  data( with 1 column email) into a mysql database (from .csv files) using Python and MySQL Connector.

I can't figure out why I am getting the error:

***mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: File 'Canada_supp.csv' could not be read***

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='',user='',passwd='',database='',client_flags=[ClientFlag.LOCAL_FILES]
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

path='Canada_supp.csv'
query1="""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE supp_20"""%(path)
cursor.execute(query1)
mydb.commit()
print(cursor.rowcount)
print query1
```

Answer (score 0):

got the solution on excuting the below command:

```
cursor.execute('''LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table_name''')
```